# Express middleware run in another context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm creating a middleware module for express and I can't seem to get the object properties to pass when used in "app.use"

```
function test (mytest) {
    this.mytest = mytest;
};

test.prototype.showTest = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(this.mytest);
    next();
};

var s = new test('foo');

router.post('/login', s.showTest, function (req, res) {
    res.send('test');
});
```

This code will output "undefined" instead of "foo." How can I get it to retain the object properties?

Comment: `s.showTest.bind(s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return your function in the creation of the object:

```
function test (mytest) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(mytest);
        next();
    };
};

var s = test('foo');

router.post('/login', s, function (req, res) {
    res.send('test');
});
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `s.showTest` in your code sample.  `s` is going to be a function in your redesigned `test()` constructor so it's unclear to me where `s.showTest` comes from.

Comment: @jfriend00 s.showTest has been replaced by the function returned by the constructor.

Comment: You mean now that you've edited your answer to remove the reference to `s.showTest`.   Also, there's no reason to use `s = new test('foo')` any more.  You can just do `s = test('foo');`.

Comment: @jfriend00 You know, I'm sorry that I've made a mistake but you're really not adding to the already sour connotation that comes with using stackoverflow. Someone made a mistake, edit it and move on.

Comment: I was pointing out a mistake you made that was material.  If you had just said: "Thx, I've corrected it now", all would have been well.  But I thought you were saying my comment was in error and that your error was never there and I reacted to that.  Never mind, I'll move on elsewhere.